# How to divide list in a single ul into 3 columns

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a ul has list inside it. Is it possible to divide the list into 3 columns.

The structure of my html is like this:

```
 <ul>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>

     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>

     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
 </ul>
```

**Problem:** I cannot directly edit the page and divide the list in to 3 ul. I must edit it via CSS.

**Output:** The final output should have 3 columns. And edited via CSS

Please help me.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns for further information on the properties used in monkeyinsight’s answer.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```css
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: Under WebKit at least, this is going to remove the list bullets.

Comment: Hello there.. I tried your answer but it does not work for mozilla and chrome.

Comment: @minitech `li:before {content: '● ';font-size: 10px;}` :)

Comment: If you use:
`list-style-position: inside;`

You will see the bullets.

Comment: Am I the only one who was like "WOAH, is this THAT simple?". I was going to calculate number of columns, do some hard html/css stuff etc

Comment: does not work properly in Safari - it makes the columns aligned but it usually leaves the overflow gap

Answer (score 22):

CSS3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can also do this as well:

```
ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
ul li {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

Above css will create the following layout:

```
+--------------------+
|  01  |  05  |  09  |
+--------------------+
+--------------------+
|  02  |  06  |  10  |
+--------------------+
+--------------------+
|  03  |  07  |  11  |
+--------------------+
+--------------------+
|  04  |  08  |  12  |
+--------------------+
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.list {
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.col1 {
  background: blue;
}

.col2 {
  background: orange;
}

.col3 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="col1">Test 1</li>
  <li class="col1">Test 2</li>
  <li class="col1">Test 3</li>
  <li class="col1">Test 4</li>

  <li class="col2">Test 5</li>
  <li class="col2">Test 6</li>
  <li class="col2">Test 7</li>
  <li class="col2">Test 8</li>

  <li class="col3">Test 9</li>
  <li class="col3">Test 10</li>
  <li class="col3">Test 11</li>
  <li class="col3">Test 12</li>
</ul>
```

In case you wants the following layout:

```
+-----------------------+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
+-----------------------+
+-----------------------+
|  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  | 
+-----------------------+
+-----------------------+
|  9  |  10 |  11 | 12  |
+-----------------------+
```

you can use the following css:

```
ul {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
ul li {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.list li:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background: blue;
}

.list li:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background: orange;
}

.list li:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background: green;
}
.list li:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>

  <li>Test 5</li>
  <li>Test 6</li>
  <li>Test 7</li>
  <li>Test 8</li>

  <li>Test 9</li>
  <li>Test 10</li>
  <li>Test 11</li>
  <li>Test 12</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12):

if you don't like the column-count answer (I like it myself but it's true that support is "iffy", specially in IE), you can simply do this:

```
ul li{width:33.333333%; float:left;}
```

or even

```
ul{display:block;}
ul li{display:inline-block;}
```

But this way you will have 3 columns although in different order: instead of

```
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6   9
```

you'll have

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

so consider the pros and cons.

Personally, I'd use monkeyinsight's answer, but if you need another option, here you have

Comment: Thank you. The approach ul{display:block;}
ul li{display:inline-block;} is the best choice in my opinion.

Comment: What does the comma do in `width:33,333333%`? Are commas interchangeable with periods in numbers/percentages?

Comment: it's an auto-correct typo, in my language and locale (Spanish, Argentina), commas replace periods

Answer (score 6):

Using CSS Grid

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<div class="cont">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="list-item">*</li>
        <li class="list-item">*</li>
        <li class="list-item">*</li>    
        <li class="list-item">*</li>
        <li class="list-item">*</li>
        <li class="list-item">*</li>    
        <li class="list-item">*</li>
        <li class="list-item">*</li>
        <li class="list-item">*</li>    
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And The CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anthony_718/pen/ExgyKGr